# How could I Create this template programmatically in wpf?

Tags: c#, xaml

How could I Create this template programmatically in wpf?

I`ve problem in margin definition

how could add RelativeSource, AncestorType And Binding use only in runtime and via C# code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_Name">
      <DockPanel>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" 
                      Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" 
                      Margin="{Binding Level,
                             Converter={StaticResource 
                                        LevelToIndentConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                             AncestorType=
                                             {x:Type l:TreeListViewItem}}}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                                 AncestorType=
                                                  {x:Type l:TreeListViewItem}}}"
                      ClickMode="Press"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
      </DockPanel>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasItems,
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                               AncestorType={x:Type l:TreeListViewItem}}}" 
                     Value="False">
          <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                  Property="Visibility"
                  Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What effort have you done?

Comment: Adding some of the code you´ve writen trying to do it should help making it more appealing to other users so they feel good answering the question.

Comment: main problem is that: i wanna create a treelist view without any .xaml file!